# Offline C++ syntax highlighter

Tags: gratis, software-development, c++, windows-10, offline

I am looking for a C++ syntax highlighter, i.e. an application that takes plain text input (C++ code, of course) and provides formatted code as output (HTML, RTF).

Why do I need that? Yes, any IDE will do the syntax highlighting. However, I sometimes need code in Word documents or Powerpoint presentations. And I want syntax highlighting there as well.

I can't use online code tools (https://godbolt.com would do that nicely) due to company policies. I am not allowed to post code there.

Requirements:

- works on Windows
- works offline, no Internet
- is gratis, Open Source preferred

Basically such a tool needs a minimal UI. A single textbox would be enough. I paste the Code from clipboard and I copy it back to the clipboard. That's it. No export functionality, no opening of files, nothing else needed.

Comment: not exactly your requirement so not posting this as an answer, but for the purpose of "code on slides for a presentation" I use sli.dev https://sli.dev/

Comment: @julaine: thank you. Certainly interesting.

Answer (score 1):

## VSCodium

You can simply copy your code and the highlighting will be copied, too. See screenshot where I've copied from VSCodium and pasted it to LibreOffice.

[VSCodium](https://github.com/VSCodium/vscodium) is

- open source
- works offline
- works on Windows

[image]

**Note**: that I skipped your request for exporting to HTML as it seems to me you would be fine with copy+paste, e.g. copy the code and paste it into your Word or PowerPoint documents, right?

Comment: Sure, I think the clipboard will contain either HTML or RTF.